# Hold command prompt when running commands from Run Dialog box

Tags: cmd

Running `ipconfig` from the Run Dialog box works but the command prompt closes immediately.

Any way to hold the screen while running commands from Run Dialog box?

Comment: `cmd /k command`

Comment: The console closes if there aren't any programs attached to it. Using `cmd /k ipconfig` leaves an instance of cmd.exe attached to the console after ipconfig.exe exits.

Comment: Damn I was trying `pause` but this is simpler. Thanks.